# My stylesheet is no loading into my jsp file. how to solve this?

Tags: css, jsp

login.jsp page is not loading the css stylesheet. Crosschecked the path but in vain.

Snaps of the code and the directory:
[enter image description here][1]

jsp code:

[enter image description here][2]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hall Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--==============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Include code and markup in your question as text, not as an image.  Images are hard to read, impossible to search, impossible to copy into an editor, and impossible for sight impaired users to read.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either root path since they are public resources (add the `/`):

```
href="/vendor/bootstrap/...`
```

or use the page context like this :

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vendor/bootstrap/..."
```

Comment: did you try relative path ? ```'../vendor/bootstrap/...'```

Comment: are any of your assets accebile in public ? using the url ?